# Deploy only java file without deploying the WAR

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I have a jsp based web application.

The source is kept in `C:/MyApp/src`. Here it contains the controllers and other `.java` files.

After building the application via eclipse. I copied the `.war` file to `Apache/WebApps` folder. Apache Tomcat expanded it and the web-application is working perfectly.

From the last couple of days I edited a lot of pages directly in `Apache/WebApps` folder. Now I want to edit a `.java` file in `C:/MyApp/src/..`

Now I want to use that updated `.java` file in my `Apache/WebApps` but don't want to rebuild the whole code via eclipse. If I do so my changes that I made in `Apache/WebApps` folder will be lost.

What should I do?

Comment: Apache is not an Program, Apache is an Foundation. Im pretty sure, the Foundation does not extract your WAR-Files. Please be more specific. ;)

Comment: @coure2011 I think you are using Apache Tomcat if I am not wrong and not apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the changes as suggested by [@bpgergo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/176569/bpgergo) or else ...

You can configure your tomcat server with Eclipse and are starting and stopping the server from eclipse then you can `add your project` to the configured Server in eclipse.

Eclipse can be configured to auto-deploy the changes to the server, so whenever you change anything like a JSP or a java file the server will automatically take the changes without you deploying your WAR file.

But since java changes are not hot-deployable eclipse would restart the server whenever you save changes to your java file.

If you want to deploy java changes without restarting the server you can also try using **[JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/eclipse-eval/)** (it is free for 30 days :-)).

**For now I would suggest** (if you don't want to go the above mentioned way. The following is a very crude method and should be avoided in the future)

1. compile the `.java` file into a `.class` in eclipse.
2. shut-down the server
3. copy the `.class` file to the exact location on the server in `WEB-INF/classes/..`
4. restart the server
5. This would keep your JSP changes intact and also will reflect the `.java` changes

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

you should

1. merge back all you modifications from the deployment folder (Apache/WebApps) to the source folder (C:/MyApp/src/). Make sure you can rebuild the current version from the sources.
2. start using some sort a [version control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) tool, even if you work only on your local machine (I recommend [Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git#Installing-on-Windows))
3. start using [build tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249871/what-is-a-build-tool), instead of having Eclipse build your war from the sources. I recommend [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) or [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/)

Comment: -1 You are right, but this does not solve his problem. He congrete dont like to have the WebApps-folder deleted. Neither maven nor ant would help here.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Plugin

```
http://andrei.gmxhome.de/filesync/index.html
```

And work with extracted war-files.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, since he is talking about a `.java` file, java files are unlike jsp and require a deployment to reflect the changes. This tool will just sync the files from file system with eclipse.

Comment: Eclipse compile .java to .class right? The plugin the .class-files to the Server too! Then the deployment-scanner of the server starts up. Thats all deployment! (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMtcjgTyP-g @ 4min)